# Mongodb updateOne with $or operator updates always the first document in the collection even if there is no match

Tags: mongodb

I have the following function which adds a comment to a private room between two users.

```
saveComment: async function(comment) {
    const id1 = comment.sender + comment.receiver;
    const id2 = comment.receiver + comment.sender;
   
    await Room.updateOne({
        $or: [{
            roomId: 'njnj' //should be id1
        }, {
            roomId: 'sadas' //should be id2
        }],
        $push: {
            comments: comment
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

The problem is that the updateOne method always updates the first document (Room) in the collection
even if I set random ids in the query and there is no match. I think the issue is that I don't use the $or operator properly but I am unable to find any mistakes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a issue with bracket, you have combined both query and update part in same bracket, to correct it to,

```
await Room.updateOne(
  {
    $or: [
      { roomId: 'njnj' }, //should be id1 
      { roomId: 'sadas' } //should be id2
    ]
  }
  {      
    $push: { comments: comment }
  }
).catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
```